# Create dictionary from multiple lines in a file (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, string, dictionary, loops

I am trying to take multiple lines from a file and compile into a dictionary. Here is the example:

I want to create a dictionary for each "datacenter" with key value pairs "name" "location" etc.  I am having trouble iterating through the file correctly.  If the information was all in one line, it would be easier.

> datacenter { // 1 server(s)
>
> name     "datacenter1"
>
> location "china"
>
> contact  "email@domain.com"
>
> server "server-1"
>
> }
>
> datacenter { // 3 server(s)
>
> name     "datacenter2"
>
> location "japan"
>
> contact  "email@domain.com"
>
> server "testserver"
>
> server "mainserver"
>
> server "anotherserver"
>
> }

Comment: What language you are using? some code might be useful

Comment: Agreed.  Sort of need to know what language you're using; it would also be nice to see what you've tried so far.  

Having said that, multiple lines might make your life easier as you can look for line break characters (\n, \r).

Comment: That's an example of the file or of the resulting dictionary you would like to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

If python (like tagged), maybe try:

```
file.readlines()
lines.find('}')
```

Comment: It is python. output should be datacenter1{name:'blah',location:'blah',contact:'blah,server:'blah',}

Comment: file.readlines()
lines.find('}')
line.find works, not "lines", it gives a value 0,-1, or 3.  trying some ideas with it. thanks